# imagesloaded and masonry and infinite scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, infinite-scroll, masonry, imagesloaded

I am currently using the code from https://gist.github.com/gregrickaby/10383879. When I use this for my tumblr blog, the masonry doesn't work properly and instead there are spaces in between my pics like so [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwtxy.jpg)

Here is a copy & paste of the code:

(function() {

```
// Main content container
var $container = $('#content');

// Masonry + ImagesLoaded
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        // selector for entry content
        itemSelector: '.entry',
        columnWidth: 200
    });
});

// Infinite Scroll
$container.infinitescroll({

    // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
    navSelector  : "div#pagination",
    // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    nextSelector : "div#pagination a#nextPage",
    // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    itemSelector : ".entry",

    // finished message
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.'
        }
    },

    // Trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            // show elems now they're ready
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        });

});

/**
 * OPTIONAL!
 * Load new pages by clicking a link
 */

// Pause Infinite Scroll
$(window).unbind('.infscr');

// Resume Infinite Scroll
$('.nav-previous a').click(function(){
    $container.infinitescroll('retrieve');
    return false;
});
```

})();

The html is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><html><head>


<title>{title}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="{RSS}" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1220" />


<!-- DEFAULT VARIABLES -->
<meta name="color:Background" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="color:Blog Title" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="color:Text" content="#000000" />
<meta name="color:Link" content="#292929"/>
<meta name="color:Link Hover" content="#292929" />
<meta name="color:Header Text" content="#FFFFFF"/>
<meta name="color:Header Background" content="#292929" />
<meta name="image:Background" content="" />
<meta name="if:3 Columns" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:4 Columns" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:5 Columns" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:6 Columns" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Link Dividers A" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Link Dividers B" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Link Dividers C" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Rounded Photos" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Compact Posts" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Show Blog Title" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Drop Down Ask Box" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Header Transparent" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Header Fixed" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Blog Title A" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Blog Title B" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Blog Title C" content="1"/>
<meta name="text:Ask Title" content="Message" />
<meta name="text:Link One" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link One Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link Two" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link Two Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link Three" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link Three Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link Four" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Four Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Five" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Five Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Six" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Six Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Seven" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Seven Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Eight" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Eight Title" content="" />
<!---   STYLESHEETS & STATIC UPLOADS   --->
<link href="http://static.tumblr.com/6jwx45k/VUxmq9xvq/animation.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton|Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- Bebas Font -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ts2nqrf/Msal8du92/cufon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ts2nqrf/mNQl8du9p/bebas.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.DOM.ready(function() { Cufon.replace('.tw_font_bebas', { fontFamily: 'bebas', hover:true }); $('.bebas').css('visibility','visible'); }); </script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6jwx45k/qnrmqhe43/ifie1.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6jwx45k/QcKmqhe47/ifie2.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is quite possible that your classes and IDs don't match since you are copying from elsewhere. Your HTML will also be needed to solve your problem.

Comment: @chloe784 I did change them to match. I'm trying to fix this theme: http://themesbyjames.com/empire . I just updated the question with the html

Comment: I would suggest contacting the theme author.